# increase download speed

Tags: firefox, steam, download-speed

I have subscribed to a service that claims providing 100mbps. Speedtest shows between 80-90mbps, which is OK for me; however when I want to download a file in firefox which shows 1mbps, or steam which shows 10mbps. Why is that?

I searched to know if I would be able to allocate some bandwidth to certain applications, or increase the bandwidth limit if possible. I encountered QoS, a service provided by some routers to allocate different bandwidths. My router is hg253s which doesn't have that I suppose (I read the user manual, and couldn't find anything about QoS there). Furthermore, I tried to configure Firefox in about:config (.i.e max-persistent-connections-per-server). Please bare in mind that I am a newbie.

Is there any way I can increase bandwidth for some applications? Thanks.

Comment: You should not only do research but share it with us ;-) Are you aware of the difference between Mega**bytes** and Mega**bits** ? Afaik, Firefox and Steam show Megabytes/s only as far as a I know, and 10 Megabytes/s=80Megabit/s, so that would be perfectly reasonable. 1MB/s is not enough, but maybe the download server is the slow part here?

Comment: Adding to pLumo's comment, ISP's generally market their connection in bits/second. You need to remove the confusion if your ISP is marketing in terms of bits/second or bytes/second. How about visiting https://fast.com or https://www.speedtest.net/ and testing again? Both will show results in bits/second.

Comment: @pLumo I am sorry I missed that. Thank you for clarifying. Actually I didn't pay enough attention to bit bytes part. So that makes firefox 8mbps. Still a bit slow regarding my expectations. Could you elaborate on this? Thanks.

Comment: @Kulfy Sir, actually speedtest shows around 80-90. Testing again, it shows 91.51 megabits per second. And my ISP claims it is 100 megabits per econd. I am OK with this result; however, how can I make firefox benefit (a little) larger portion of that speed? Considering pLumo's comment firefox is still 8 megabits per second. Thank you for your patience and note that I am new to this networking world.

Comment: 8MB/s is probably the limitation on the other end. If your Speedtest you take in Firefox shows 91Mbit/s it is totally fine. I also have 100Mbit/s and have speeds around 8-9 MB/s normally.

Comment: @HakanDemir Your download speed also depends on the download server. Did you try downloading files from other server, for example, Google Drive?

Comment: @Kulfy actually the file is the ubuntu 20.04 iso file which is 2.6 GB. Firefox was showing 1MB/s. I tried using wget. It shows 10MB/s. It looks like working, but not a feasible solution for people who want to use firefox (chrome also shows 1MB/s for me).

Answer (score 2):

The plan from your ISP is your bandwidth , which you said is 100Mbps.
Your download speed is roughly around 1/8th of your bandwidth.

> Edit: This line doesn't mean you get 1/8th of what you paid for. You
> are getting the full bandwidth. Its just that the units have changed.
> Your download speed and bandwidth are measure in different unit. Take
> a guess which one your ISP uses to advertise its plans? The one which
> makes their plan look good. Its like measuring the vehicle speed in km
> and mile. Your dealer will advertise top speed in km/hr but your car meter will show you speed in miles. (just imagine this scenario, i know that is not how it works with cars). Its almost like this example.

Your download speed will never be the same as your bandwidth.  Download speed depends on various factors.

1. Download server: if the server that the file is being downloaded has capped download speed for that file at lets say 1Mbps then you will never be able to download that file at higher speed. Irrespective of your bandwidth.
2. Multiple Thread downloads: If your download manager supports it then you can take example 1 and create 10 connection to that server and download that same file at 10x speed. But this like I said your download manager needs to support this. I am not sure if firefox download manager supports this or not. Try using some other download manager.
3. Then there are other factors like your computer. Is it capable of downloading large files at that speed? If your network card drivers are not up to date then it might be the reason behind slow speeds. Is there some other software that's using the bandwidth as well?
4. Your router plays an important part as well. The Wi-Fi band you are connected to, distance from your router. Other devices connected to the router and their data consumption as well.

So as you can see, its mix of all these things and few more that determines your download speed or internet speed. And like I said, your internet speed is not the same as your bandwidth. You can easily find numerous articles and videos on the internet explaining the difference. But if you are getting that much speed on steam then you are getting good speed as per your bandwidth.

Comment: I have a 100Mbps plan and I get 100Mbps bandwidth...

Comment: Read the first few words. that's what i said.

Comment: It seemed what you said was you generally only get 1/8th of the bandwidth you pay for, which is not true. Sorry if I misread it.

Comment: yea, that first sentence is confusing, it makes it sound like its a slower speed, when it's really a change in units.  There are no details regarding the difference in units in this answer, which is probably the issue.

Comment: Edited first line to make it simple. But the in short, download speed and bandwidth are two different things. Also, both of them depends on multiple factors.